# Authoring a Negative Test Class for a Calculator Class

Tags: unit-test, trailhead

I seem to be stuck on this trailhead section on writing negative test classes. I have the class authored as follows but as this doesn't seem to reference an sObject, I am wondering what steps to take to author a test class.

```
public class Calculator {
 public class CalculatorException extends Exception{}

  public static Integer addition(Integer a, Integer b){
return a + b;
}

public static Integer subtraction(Integer a, Integer b){
return a - b;
}

public static Integer multiply(Integer a, Integer b){
if(b==0 || a==0){
  throw new CalculatorException('It doesn\'t make sense to multiply by zero');
}
return a * b;
}

public static Decimal divide(Integer numerator, Integer denominator){
if(denominator == 0){
  throw new CalculatorException('you still can\'t divide by zero');
 }
Decimal returnValue = numerator / denominator;
if(returnValue < 0){
  throw new CalculatorException('Division returned a negative value.' + returnValue);
}
return returnValue;
}


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A unit test doesn't have to touch the database. In fact, some people would argue that a good unit test *doesn't* touch the database.

The fundamental principle of testing is that you invoke your code and make a claim through an assertion, that the system will verify for you, about what the code does. A positive test would provide "good" input and assert that the code did what it was supposed to do. A negative test would provide "bad" input (like `null`, or values that are nonsensical for the code being tested) and assert that the code handled that bad input correctly.

Let's look at `divide()`:

```
public static Decimal divide(Integer numerator, Integer denominator){

    if(denominator == 0){
        throw new CalculatorException('you still can\'t divide by zero');
    }

    Decimal returnValue = numerator / denominator;
    if (returnValue < 0){
      throw new CalculatorException('Division returned a negative value.' + returnValue);
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

We have a clear *positive* case: validate that the division method does in fact divide things.

```
@isTest
public static void divide_does_divide() {
    System.assertEqual(1.5, Calculator.divide(3, 2), 'correct division result');
}
```

We also have a clear *negative* case: division by zero is Bad, and we should handle it cleanly. We can test this too, by providing bad input and validating that the expected outcome happens:

```
@isTest
public static void divide_throws_exception_for_division_by_zero() {
    Boolean caught = false;
    try {
        Calculator.divide(1, 0);
    } catch (Calculator.CalculatorException e) {
        System.assertEquals('you still can\'t divide by zero', e.getMessage(), 'caught the right exception');
        caught = true;
    }
    System.assert(caught, 'threw expected exception');
}
```

This does a couple of  things:

- it makes sure that the code throws an exception when we provide bad input;
- it ensures that the code fails for the correct reason and provides the expected feedback.

This allows us to move forward with confidence that our code handles everything that might be thrown at it effectively.

A similar pattern can be used to cover the other negative case for `divide()`, and for the other methods in this class as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question through google search and had the same problem @medhanie had where I was only getting 93% and couldn't figure out why my negative test couldn't produce a negative number for the division problem.

The reason is that Salesforce is rounding up so my example of 3/-6 produced the answer -0.5 which was rounded up to 0 and wouldn't throw the exception.

Just wanted to add that to this question in case someone else has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

For my friends who stucked at 93% code coverage, here is what I did to resolve the issue. All we need is to tweak the function call by passing a negative value of numerator.

```
Calculator.divide(-12,2);
```

[image]